Redirected you too many times issue in the Sitecore headless SXA Redirect
I am working on the Sitecore Headless With Next.js Application
We use custom event handlers to automatically create source and destination URLs whenever a content author renames or moves an item. However, if an item is renamed and then renamed back to its original name, two URLs are created.
Please refer to the screenshot below.

The issue we’re facing is that accessing the actual page URL results in a Redirected you too many times error.
Actual Page URL:
http://localhost:3000/uat-redirect-test



You have created your own redirect loop, those pages are redirecting to each other. You need to fix your code to not create a redirect loop

You have to modify your custom event handler logic to correct this behavior. You can modify it like -
if (*redirect map list* has *renamed value*)
{
    remove all entries from *redirect map list* with *renamed value* as source
}

This should avoid Redirected you too many times scenario.
Hope this helps !
